# Windows cannot find path specified when using windows install directory as variable in vbs

Tags: vbscript

Windows cannot find the path specified when using the %windir% location as a variable. Also, does anyone know if 64 bit computers have system 3s folders? I know that the variable works because i have used it in a messagebox. Here is my code, please help if you can.

```
set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

windowsdir = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")

MsgBox(windowsdir)

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""windowsdir & \System32\dvdplay.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Sorry, i am trying to use this same method to create a folder and now i am getting a "bad file name or number" error. Please help if you can.

```
dim filesys, newfolder, newfolderpath
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sWinDir : sWinDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
sCmd = """" & sWinDir & "\System32\test"""
WScript.Echo 3, sCmd, "'concatenation' solution"

newfolderpath = """"& sCmd& ""
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not filesys.FolderExists(newfolderpath) Then
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath)
End If
```

Comment: Please don't re-define your original question, but post a new one (possibly refering to the former). Your current problem is: while the shell needs quotes to *parse* a filespec containing spaces correctly, the FSO methods taking file/folderspecs as parameters *know* that a spec with spaces is still just one spec. So never use quotes for such specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with .Run or .Exec, you should use a temporary variable to store and display the command (at least until 'it works'):

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo 0, oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
Dim sCmd
sCmd = """windowsdir & \System32\dvdplay.exe"""
WScript.Echo 1, sCmd, "no variable interpolation in VBScript"
sCmd = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("""%windir%\System32\dvdplay.exe""")
WScript.Echo 2, sCmd, "'no concatenation' solution"
Dim sWinDir : sWinDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
sCmd = """" & sWinDir & "\System32\dvdplay.exe"""
WScript.Echo 3, sCmd, "'concatenation' solution"
```

output:

```
cscript 19367777.vbs
0 C:\WINDOWS
1 "windowsdir & \System32\dvdplay.exe" no variable interpolation in VBScript
2 "C:\WINDOWS\System32\dvdplay.exe" 'no concatenation' solution
3 "C:\WINDOWS\System32\dvdplay.exe" 'concatenation' solution
```

As VBScript does not splice variable content into string literals, you'll have to concatenate the parts (second best solution, in my opinion) or apply .ExpandEnvironmentStrings() to the command containing `%windir%`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, worked perfectly and was explained well.

Comment: Both the `Run` and the `Exec` method do expand environment variables, so something like `oShell.Run "%windir%\System32\dvdplay.exe"` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

On 32 bit windows you just have System32..

On 64 bit windows you have:

- System32 (which contains **64 bit** libraries)
- SysWOW64 (which has **32 bit** libraries that run in 'Windows on Windows 64' emulation layer)

I know, its confusing.

On either architecture, `%WINDIR%` should be the same. If you're only ever running your script on 64 bit systems, you might be able to get away with just changing System32 for SysWOW64.

What you *may* need to be careful of when running scripts on both 32 and 64, is: *"Which scripting host is associated with .vbs files?"* Generally if you just double click a VBS on 64 bit, the interpreter will be: `C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe` (i.e. the 64 bit host) which means that, for example `%PROGRAMFILES%` expands to `C:\Program Files`. Expand the same variable in `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\WScript.exe` (32 bit) and you get `C:\Program Files (x86)`

For a long time I've had framework code that allows a script to 're-run itself' in the 32-bit host, just for cross compatibility.

Comment: Thank you. I agree it is confusing. I will experiment with vbscripts on different computers to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that sometimes when updating Visual Studio, or SQL Server, for example, that the `Path` gets a little too full, or perhaps the `%systemroot%` entry gets "pushed down" because of new entries.

If your system cannot find `%windir%`, then look at your system `Path`, and make sure the *first* few entries are thus:

```
%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;   ...etc
```

And then make sure that the system variable `windir` is set to `C:\Windows`

You may have to reboot.  This did the trick for me.