# create a folder in a location and getting a "bad file name or number" error

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to to create a folder in a certain location using variables, and i am getting a "bad file name or number" error. Please help if you can.

```
dim filesys, newfolder, newfolderpath
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sWinDir : sWinDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
sCmd = " & sWinDir & """"\System32\oobe\info\pigu"""
WScript.Echo 3, sCmd, "This is a test to check the destined location"

newfolderpath = sCmd
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not filesys.FolderExists(newfolderpath) Then
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The instruction

```
sCmd = " & sWinDir & """"\System32\oobe\info\pigu"""
```

creates the literal string

```
 & sWinDir & ""\System32\oobe\info\pigu"
```

which, as a matter of fact, is not a valid path, i.e. a bad file name.

`FileSystemObject` methods already take care of spaces in a path, so you don't need to put a path between double quotes for them (or rather, they will cause the path to become invalid, because double quotes aren't valid characters in a path). Change the line to this:

```
sCmd = sWinDir & "\System32\oobe\info\pigu"
```

or (better) use the [`BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method:

```
newfolderpath = filesys.BuildPath(sWinDir, "System32\oobe\info\pigu")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is unknown territory for me and i can now begin to learn more about it. The word pigu is an embarassing reference by the way!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at sCmd:

```
>> sCmd = " & sWinDir & """"\System32\oobe\info\pigu"""
>> WScript.Echo 3, sCmd, "This is a test to check the destined location"
>>
3  & sWinDir & ""\System32\oobe\info\pigu" This is a test to check the destined location
>>
```

you'll agree that a folder named `& sWinDir & ""\System32\oobe\info\pigu"` should not be created. The .FolderExists and .CreateFolder methods need plain folderspecs just as `dir` would show them.

My answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19367777/603855) gave you two ways to build a file/folder spec with quotes to satisfy .Run/.Exec; surely you can leave off the quotes to obey the laws of the FSO.

Comment: Thank you, all of your input and comments have been helpful, and I now hope to develop in this area of vbs.